# value of type 'some View' has no member 'onSubmit'

Tags: swiftui

I cannot use .onSubmit function in my simple TextField. I want to perform the following function when I tap return on my keyboard. Is there any function without using a button?

```
struct Model: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tappingSwitches: TapToggle
    @AppStorage("scrollToIndex") var scrollToIndex: Int?
    @State private var numNum: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
             
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            HStack {
                TextField("#", text: $numNum)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .font(.title2)
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 35)
                    .background(Color("cTabColor"))
                    .cornerRadius(20)
                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)

                    .onSubmit(of: .text) { // The error of value of type 'some View' has no member 'onSubmit' is appeared here
                        withAnimation(.spring()) {
                            if let songNum = Int(hymnNumber) {
                                scrollToIndex = songNum
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color("cTextColor"))
            .background(Color("cColor"))
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            ViewModel()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `onSubmit` was added in iOS 15. Are you using the Xcode beta?

Comment: Oh I see. No, I am using IOS 14. Is there any function that I can use without .onSubmit? Like onChange or something?

Comment: Look at (now deprecated): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:text:oneditingchanged:oncommit:)-588cl